# Flutter: filter List<Map<String, dynamic>> by items in a list

Tags: flutter, list, dictionary, filter

I have the following block of code where I am returning a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>? getData(String category,
      List<String> levels, int levelIndex, bool completed) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> allData = [];
    try {
      //String? email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
      var doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("skills")
          .doc(category)
          .collection(levels[levelIndex])
          .get();
      allData.addAll(doc.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList());
      return allData;
    } catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

One of the fields of the list is a list of strings called `completedBy` and I am trying to filter the data such that it returns only the items that either contain or don't a certain string in the `completedBy` list. So, basically something that would conceptually look like this:

```
static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>? getData(String category,
      List<String> levels, int levelIndex, bool completed) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> allData = [];
    try {
      String? email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
      var doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("skills")
          .doc(category)
          .collection(levels[levelIndex])
          .get();
      allData.addAll(doc.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList());
      if (completed) {
        return allData.where((e) => e["completedBy"].contains(email)).toList();
      } else {
        return allData.where((e) => e["completedBy"].doesNotContain(email)).toList();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

except the methods `contains` and `doesNotContain` do not exist for type `dynamic`. How would I go about this?

I do have another method where I could potentially filter the data. The method returns a `Future<List<SkillsCard>>` where the `SkillsCard` class is defined as follows:

```
class SkillsCard {
  final String name;
  final String? description;
  final List completedBy;

  SkillsCard({
    required this.name,
    this.description,
    required this.completedBy,
  });
```

The method currently looks as follows:

```
static Future<List<SkillsCard>> readData(List<Map<String, dynamic>>? data) {
    Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> x = Stream.fromIterable(data!);
    return x.map((event) => SkillsCard.fromJson(event)).toList();
  }
```

and I was thinking that I could filter it something like this:

```
static Future<List<SkillsCard>> readData(List<Map<String, dynamic>>? data) {
    String? email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
    Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> x = Stream.fromIterable(data!);
    return x.where((event) => SkillsCard.fromJson(event).completedBy.contains(email)).toList();
  }
```

since the contains function does exist for completedBy because it is no longer dynamic, but now is a List. The problem is that when I try to do it like that I get an error because the return is a `Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>` when the method is looking for a `Future<List<SkillsCard>>`.
For reference my `fromJson` method looks as follows:

```
static SkillsCard fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return SkillsCard(name: data['name'], completedBy: data['completedBy']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what comes from `FirebaseFirestore` you can achive what you want how below code shows.
(You have to analyze it, improve it, so use it as something to start from:)

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>? getData(
    String category, List<String> levels, int levelIndex, bool completed) async {
 
  bool completed = false;
  try {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> allData = []; // If is a Map
    String email = "mail@mail.com";
    String key = "name";

    var resultFromMap = allData
        .where((Map<String, dynamic> mp) =>
            mp.containsKey(key) && (mp[key] as SkillsCard).completedBy.contains(email) == completed)
        .toList();
    
    // You can return directly   resultFromMap here
    
  } catch (e) {}

  try {
    List<SkillsCard> allData = []; // // If is a SkillsCard
    String email = "mail@mail.com"; 

    var resultFormSkillsCard = allData.where((SkillsCard sk) => sk.completedBy.contains(email) == completed);
    // Convert resultFormSkillsCard in your needs then return it as it have to be
    
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }
  
  return something here;
  
}
```